# My function inserts data into the DB at times and doesn't at times

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

I'm developing a web form where I wish to upload a document related to a particular user into a folder and make a respective entry for the same in MySql server database. Now whenever I submit my details of my document, it uploads the document just fine but at times it skips the entry into the data base.

Code Segment 1

```
protected void ImageButton2_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    String path = Server.MapPath("~/AdminUploads/");
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        Response.Write(FileUpload1.FileName);
        try
        {
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(path + FileUpload1.FileName);
            DOCUPLOADED doc = new DOCUPLOADED();
            doc.DOCTYPE = Int32.Parse(DropDownList2.SelectedValue);
            doc.DOCID = TextBox4.Text;
            doc.FILEPATH = path + FileUpload1.FileName;
            doc.FORUSER = Int64.Parse(TextBox5.Text);
            doc.FILENAME = TextBox6.Text;

            uploaddoc ud = new uploaddoc(doc);

            if (ud.upload())
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Addition succesfull');<script>");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Fatal error : addition unsuccesfull');</script>");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Error : File was not uploaded ');</script>");
        }
    }
```

Code Segment 2

```
public class uploaddoc
{
    private DOCUPLOADED doc;
    public uploaddoc(DOCUPLOADED doc)
    {
        this.doc = doc;
    }
    public bool upload()
    {
        if (doc != null)
        {
            dbcfDataContext dc = new dbcfDataContext();
            dc.DOCUPLOADEDs.InsertOnSubmit(doc);
            try
            {
                dc.SubmitChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //
            }
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

ID is supposed to be autoincremented, you can see 1-6 are absent,so are 9 10 etc.

[image: ID is supposed to be autoincremented,you can see 1-6 are absent,so are 9 10 etc]

`dbcfdatacontext` is the connection to database done by creating a `dbml` file and dragging the tables on to it.

Comment: Why do you ignore the exception in your `upload` method? That may give you useful information on why the error is happening.

Comment: You are returning true when doc is not null regardless the result of your database update or insert. Try to put a break point on catch block and  put "return false;".

Comment: You are using an anti-pattern here that I call Try/Squelch. In other words you go to the effort of trapping an error but then just blindly carry on as though nothing was wrong. This is horrible practice. I am guessing that your ID column is an identity? The reason there are gaps is because the identity value is incremented when an insert attempt is made even if that attempts fails. And you have no way of knowing in your code if it failed or not. And of course gaps are normal and expected in the case of deletes. And when the server reboots you will get gaps too.

Comment: @ayushprashar than you should probably use it only when it's working on insert, ignore that non working part, so take only working part and repeat it so it will work all the time

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your code:

```
public class uploaddoc
{
    private DOCUPLOADED doc;
    public uploaddoc(DOCUPLOADED doc)
    {
        this.doc = doc;
    }
    public bool upload()
    {
        if (doc != null)
        {
            dbcfDataContext dc = new dbcfDataContext();
            dc.DOCUPLOADEDs.InsertOnSubmit(doc);
            //try
            //{
                dc.SubmitChanges();
            //}
            //catch (Exception ex)
            //{
                //
            //}
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

But in all seriousness, empty catch blocks are the equivalent of shooting yourself in the foot. Don't do that.

Comment: `DataContext` is the one exception to the `IDisposable` rule. [`DataContext` cleans up after itself regardless of calling the `.Dispose()` method](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/273705/24176).